# Regex check number of letters and some characters

Tags: regex, symfony

I have these requirements for validation for a string text

- limit to minimum of 4 and maximum of 9 characters
- minimum 5 letters required and rest can be numbers or letters
- @ and spaces will not be accepted

I am using Symfony validator which accepts regex expressions.
I have no experience with regex so haven't made anything yet.

Open to implement any other methods if this is not possible with regex.

Comment: This - http://www.phpliveregex.com/ - is handy for checking regex's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below regex.

```
^(?=[0-9A-Za-z]{4,9}$)(?:[0-9A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){5}[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

- limit to minimum of 4 and maximum of 9 characters

  ```
  (?=[0-9A-Za-z]{4,9}$)
  ```
- minimum 5 letters required and rest can be numbers or letters

  ```
  (?:[0-9A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){5}[A-Za-z0-9]*$
  ```

In php,

```
preg_match('~^(?=[0-9A-Za-z]{4,9}$)(?:[0-9A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]){5}[A-Za-z0-9]*$~m', $str);
```

Comment: Comes with this error  - Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found